# Recursive call in python causes IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, recursion

I am practicing writing various sort functions in different languages. I wrote a bubble sort in python using a recursive call but I don't know how to properly terminate the recursion. As I have it now the program sorts correctly but extends beyond the parameters of my list and triggers an error: IndexError: list index out of range (on line 29) [i.e. bubblesort(randomList)]

```
import random
#create a list of 10 random ints between 0-99 to be sorted
def makeRandomList():
    unsortedList=[]
    for i in range(10):
        unsortedList.append(random.randrange(100))
    print unsortedList
    return unsortedList


def bubblesort(randomList):
    i=0
    while i<=len(randomList):
        if randomList[i] > randomList[i+1]:
            randomList[i], randomList[i+1] = randomList[i+1], randomList[i]
            i+=1
            if i<len(randomList):
                bubblesort(randomList)
            else: break
        else:
            i+=1
            #for testing purposes
            print randomList
    return randomList


randomList=makeRandomList()
sortedList=bubblesort(randomList)
print "sorted list: ", sortedList
```

Comment: the problem here looks like is yours index use, with this you have to make sure that `i` and `i+1` both are less than `len(someList)` because in last case, say your list len is 3, when i is 2, i+1 is 3 and is a index out of range...

Answer (score 1):

*This error was edited from the originally posted code.*

Is this line doing what you expect?

```
randomList[-i]<[-(i+1)]
```

Here you are just comparing the element `randomlist[-i]` with the [-(i+1)]. [-(i+1)] is just an integer and not an element of `randomlist`. It should read

```
randomList[-i]<randomlist[-(i+1)]
```

if you are trying to compare the elements of the list.

**More efficient way to create a random list of size 10:**

When creating an unsorted list of integers, take advantage of `random.sample()`so you do not waste time and space iterating. In your case, `random.sample(range(100), 10).`

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. My index was running off the end of the list (that is, when i was len(randomList) my program was looking for len(randomList+1) and it wasn't terminating at the base case because then while loop was i<=len(randomList) when it should have been i<(len(randomList)-1). Here is the correct solution:

```
def bubblesort(randomList):
    i=0
    while i<(len(randomList)-1):
        if randomList[i] > randomList[i+1]:
            randomList[i], randomList[i+1] = randomList[i+1], randomList[i]
            i+=1
            if i<(len(randomList)-1):
                bubblesort(randomList)
            else: break
        else:
            i+=1
            print randomList
    return randomList
```

Comment: Also the way your recursion was defined `inorder` was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your `inOrder` function doesn't work.  i is a variable scoped to the function so setting i+=1 at the beginning means that it won't be set to that in the next recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to increase the amount of recursive calls you have:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

i would also suggest trying to avoid making recursive methods, for the reason you have.

you should run through the list to get a minimum value and max and then try and predict position of the values. So if the selected item in the list is less than 100 put it into position 10.
Or you could could check if the value before it is greater or less than it and if its less than it then do it to the value after it :) for example:

```
    Age = [10,11,20,9,10,2,1,3]

for X in range(0, len(Age)):
    if X < len(Age) - 1:
        if Age[X] > Age[X + 1]:
            Temp = Age[X + 1]
            Age[X + 1] = Age[X]
            Age[X] = Temp

print(Age)
```

the output was: `[10, 11, 9, 10, 2, 1, 3, 20]`

you would want to have a while loop surounding the for loop :)